# How to force evaluation of subquery in ActiveRecord has_many condition on each access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

The model:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :free_unids, :class_name => "Unid", 
        :conditions => ['id not in (?)',
                        (Spot.where('unid_id is not null').map(&:unid_id) + [-1])]
end
```

Accessing `@venue.free_unids` triggers an evaluation of the condition itself as we can see in the log:

```
Unid Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "unids".* FROM "unids" WHERE "unids"."venue_id" = 79 AND (id not in (4,8723,8889,-1)) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Problem is that the subquery (`Spot.where('unid_id is not null')` / `(4,8723,8889,-1)`) often does not reflect the new records inserted into `Spot` a few seconds ago. And debugging at the line where the relation is accessed (`pp Spot.where('unid_id is not null')`) yields the correct set of records, including the new ones.

To me it looks like if the subquery expression result is cached, but I have to admit that I do not quite understand the logic behind the curtains here...

Is it possible to force the evaluation of the expression on every access? Or do we need another approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up the relation approach and went for the query method solution like this:

```
  def free_unids
    return Unid.where(
      'venue_id = ? and id not in (?)', 
      id, 
      (Spot.where('unid_id is not null').map(&:unid_id) + [-1])).
      order('id')
  end
```

See my comment to Rob's answer for details on why I chose this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
@venue.reload
```

before accessing the association should work.

Comment: Thanks Rob. What I don't like about this approach is that the developer needs to be disciplined. Of course you could wrap that into a model method, but that would leave the unwanted "wrong" relation still accessible. In this case I would rather give up the relation approach in favor of a plain query method.